# Filter most read pages with Google Analytics API v4

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, analytics

I'm currently trying to obtain a list of the three most read articles on my site, using the Google Analytics Reporting API v4.

Currently, I have been able to request a list of all pages with the number of pageviews each one got in the past 30 days, and filter them by pageview.

But now I'm stuck (after browsing for answers for multiple hours) to filter so only pagepaths that include /artikels/ are shown, and limit the list to 3 results.

My current code:

```
function getReport($analytics) {



// Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "XXXXXXX";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("30daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  //Create the Dimensions object.
  $pagepath = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $pagepath->setName("ga:pagePath");

  $ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
  $ordering->setOrderType("VALUE");
  $ordering->setFieldName("ga:pageviews");
  $ordering->setSortOrder("DESCENDING");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setDimensions(array($pagepath));
  $request->setOrderBys($ordering); 
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

Could anyone please help? There is a ton of information about v3, but can't seem to find enough information about v4.
Thank you!

Comment: What you want are *filters* or *dynamic segments* - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#segments